# Previous working date in F#

Tags: f#

Quite a beginner question: given a DateTime, I want to find the previous non-weekend date in `F#`. I thus created this:

```
open System

module Date =

  let isWeekEnd (date:DateTime) =
      ((date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday) || (date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday))

  let getPreviousWorkDay date =
      while isWeekEnd date do
          let date = date.AddDays -1.0
      date
```

However, it seems I violate the fact that date is immutable. I hence wonder how to do this with a while loop and why not with a sequence by retrieving up to 3 days back and filtering the one which is nonweekend, finally taking the first...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use that while loop approach you need to declare date as mutable:

```
let getPreviousWorkDay d =
    let mutable date = d
    while isWeekEnd date do
      date <- date.AddDays -1.0
    date
```

Otherwise you can use recursion:

```
let rec getPreviousWorkDay date =
    let prevDate = date.AddDays -1.0
    if isWeekEnd prevDate then getPreviousWorkDay prevDate
    else prevDate
```

Note that if what you want is really to go one day before and then if it's a weekend go further back, your function will stay in case of sending a weekday. But you can solve it by passing an already subtracted day:

```
let getPreviousWorkDay (date:DateTime) =
  let rec loop date =
        if isWeekEnd date then loop (date.AddDays -1.0)
        else date
  loop (date.AddDays -1.0)
```

Comment: seems great! the immutable attribute makes the trick, will test this!

Comment: works, I took the liberty to correct the recurring function (which I am using) otherwise it would just have given the current date.

Answer (score 2):

The very nature of using a `while` loop means that you're going to be mutating something. If you don't want to do this and would rather go with a more functional solution then you could use a `match` expression:

```
module Date =
    let getPreviousWorkDay (date:DateTime) =
        match date.DayOfWeek with
        | DayOfWeek.Monday -> date.AddDays -3.0
        | DayOfWeek.Sunday -> date.AddDays -2.0
        | _ -> date.AddDays  -1.0
```

Here we don't need to mutate anything.

Comment: that's great! I choose the recursive solution but this one is more explicit.